# Add index to duplicated items in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, series

I wrote the following function to add indexes to duplicates in a series:

(`["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"]`
becomes `["foo 1", "foo 2", "foo 3", "bar 1", "bar 2"]`)

```
def indexer(series):
  all_labels = []
  for title in set(series): 
    label = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(series): 
      if title == series.iloc[i]:
        label.append(title)
      i += 1
    all_labels.append(label)
  final = []
  for item in all_labels:
    if len(item) > 1:
      for i, label in enumerate(item):
        final.append(label + " " + str(i+1))
    else:
      final.append(item[0])
  return final
```

There is obviously a better and cleaner way to do this, probably using Pandas groupby and agg (although I'm not sure how they behave with a single series instead of df). Would someone please shed some light on how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a DataFrame you can use `groupby` to find a cumulative count which is the label you want to concatenate to all your strings, and note the groups don't have to be in order:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "foo"], columns=["baz"])
labels = df.groupby("baz").cumcount() + 1
df["baz"] + " " + labels.astype(str)
```

which results in

```
0    foo 1
1    foo 2
2    bar 1
3    bar 2
4    foo 3
dtype: object
```

However this will also add the  `1` label to any unique values. Did you want those to remain unchanged? I assumed not since you're starting the others at  `1` instead of leaving the first in each group unchanged.

Comment: I did want the unique values to remain unchanged but with your result I can just remove " 1" from values not in df[df.duplicated()] right?

Answer (score 2):

If single appearance needs to be left alone.

> ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'John']

```
mylist = list(df)
m = map(lambda x: x[1]+ " " + str(mylist[:x[0]].count(x[1]) + 1) if mylist.count(x[1]) > 1 else x[1], enumerate(mylist))
m = list(m)
df = pd.Series(m)
df
```

Output:

```
0    foo 1
1    foo 2
2    foo 3
3    bar 1
4    bar 2
5    John
dtype: object
```

**John** didn't get any number with him. Hurray!

Comment: also an excellent answer, didn't choose as right because the other is more "Pand-onic". However this gets the results I needed

Comment: lovely ....! <3